# UINavigationController taking time to push ViewController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, objective-c-blocks

Take the following code:

```
[[[Resource alloc] init] get:@"/api/v1/basic_user/40/" params:nil completion:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSDictionary *data, NSError *connectionError) {
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    HomeViewController *homeView = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeViewController"];

    NSLog(@"pushing...");
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:homeView animated:YES];
}];
```

This prints "pushing" and after about 10(not precisely) seconds my `HomeViewController` appears.
The `initWithCoder`(the ViewController is instantiated from the Storyboard) has absolutely nothing. And that gets called just right after I push my VC.

But my `viewDidLoad` method is taking seconds to load. I can't tell how many seconds because it's not exact. It sometimes doesn't load at all! (e.g. my `HomeViewController` does not show up.

Here's the trickier part. If I move my push method outside my block everything works like a charm.

What's going on? Why is my VC so slow when inside the block?

EDIT:

The only thing that uses thread when the method in my resource is called is the code below:

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:_request queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError){
    NSLog(@"%@", [[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil] description]);
    [self toggleNetworkActivityIndicator];

    _lastResponse = response;
    success(response, data, connectionError);
}];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is whatever your doing in your resources method is on another thread through dispatch. So try wrapping your push view controller in a grand central `dispatch` back to the main queue like the following code:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // Push view controller here
});
```

This has solved some issues were when I was performing animations it would take 5-10 seconds to do something that usually only took about a half a second.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Okay where you return your success competion handler, put the code I post surrounding that instead of where I say to push the view controller. You either have an issue when returning the handler or processing the completion block. Does your get method do anything on another thread or heavy lifting as well?

Comment: I guess using AFNetworking would solve all this. Correct? The issue that my request is happening on the main thread, right?

Comment: Yes. I think that could be a possibility although I am not to sure. Did wrapping the code not work?

Comment: It did. Now the navigationcontroller shows up. I was just wondering what could be the reason. Also, I should never use NSURLConnection anyway.

Comment: Its because in your old code, the completion handler was waiting on another thread and once the main thread had time, I am assuming it picked up the code from the handler.  So that might be why your time varied every time you pushed the controller.  Now that your telling the completion handler to return to the main thread it will process that block of code almost instantly.

Comment: No problem.  When I made an app for personal use to access grade information from my school, I had a similar issue when trying to grab my grades from PowerSchool on another thread using a completion handler, and then forgot to return that block of code to the main.  I think I was stuck on the issue for a couple of days until I re-read the GCD documents.

Comment: Geez, I think I must read that to not fall for this anymore. ;p

Answer (score 2):

Swift 3

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                //write your code here
            }
        }
```